# Retrieve a csv uploaded to GridFS (mongodb)

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, gridfs

I uploaded a csv to gridfs using python and now I want to use this csv in my new python code. I tryed this:

```
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client["grid_file"]
collection = db["fs.files"]
name="csv"
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)

gout = fs.get_last_version(name)

fout = open('s.csv', 'wb')
fout.write(gout.read())
```

And it worked for me, but this method save the csv in my computer and I want to have the csv in a variable like a dataframe in my code but without saving it in my computer.
Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it, I leave my code here in case someone can help you in the future

```
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client["grid_file"]
collection = db["fs.files"]
name="csv"
                
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)

gout = fs.get_last_version(name)
        
fout = []
fout.append(gout.read())
        
fout2 = str(fout[0])
fout3= fout2.split("\\r\\n")
ListaUlt = []
for i in range(len(fout3)-1):
    ListaUlt.append(fout3[i+1].split(','))
        
df = pd.DataFrame(ListaUlt, columns =['userID', 'activity', 'timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis'])
```